# Trouble with pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

So, been reading tons of posts on here and int he Codex but just not having any luck. I have a custom post type called Work. On my portfolio page I have "posts_per_page" set to 12. In total in this custom post type I have 300 posts. I am trying to get paging working but not getting it at all.

My query:

```
        <?php
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $all_work = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'work',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'type',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array('case-study', 'portfolio')
                    ),
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => '12',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'update_post_term_cache' => false,
                'nopaging' => false,
                'paged' => 10
                )
            );
            while ( $all_work->have_posts() ) : $all_work->the_post();
        ?>
```

My code for the pagination:

```
                                        <aside id="post_nav">
                        <?php                   
global $wp_query;

$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1){

  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

  echo '<div class="page_nav">';

  echo paginate_links(array(
      'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
      'format' => '/page/%#%',
      'current' => $current_page,
      'total' => $total_pages,
      'prev_text' => 'Prev',
      'next_text' => 'Next'
    ));

  echo '</div>';

}

                        ?>              
                    </aside><!-- /#post_nav -->
```

Not getting anything though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble generating pagination links on custom query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77528/having-trouble-generating-pagination-links-on-custom-query)

Comment: I looked over that thread as well before posting and the solution doesn't seem to apply with my scenario. I have tried the suggested answer numerous times but no luck =/

Comment: OK... "Not getting anything though." Statements like that are almost always false. You must be getting _something_. What?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, the container for the paging isn't coming up with any results. So no paging is actually showing up. I added: `<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>` and changed my loop to be: `'paged' => $paged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to paginate the `$all_work` query data, but your pagination code is using the `$wp_query` data...

```
global $wp_query;

$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1){

  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
```

... for reasons unknown to me.

If you want to paginate `$all_work` you need to use the `$all_work` data. The data in `$wp-query` is not going to be correct. I suspect it is this mixing of queries that is causing the trouble, and I suspect a similar mixing up of queries that is the reason the code in suggested duplicate isn't working for you.

Something like this should work:

```
$page = (!empty($_GET['myp'])) ? $_GET['myp'] : 1;
$per_page = 1;
$base = get_queried_object();
// var_dump($base);
if (null === $base) {
  $base = site_url();
} else {
  $base = get_permalink($base->ID);
}

// $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$all_work = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
//  'tax_query' => array(
//      array(
//          'taxonomy' => 'type',
//          'field' => 'slug',
//          'terms' => array('case-study', 'portfolio')
//      ),
//  ),
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'nopaging' => false,
    'paged' => $page
  )
);

$total = $all_work->found_posts;
var_dump($total);

while ( $all_work->have_posts() ) {
  $all_work->the_post();
  the_title(0);
}

$page_args = array(
    'base'         => $base.'%_%',
    'format'       => '?myp=%#%',
    'total'        => ceil($total / $per_page),
    'current'      => $page,
    'show_all'     => True,
    'end_size'     => 1,
    'mid_size'     => 1,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'type'         => 'plain',
);

echo '<br/>';
echo paginate_links($page_args);
```

That is generic code, as I don't have your data on my server, but it should be obvious what needs to be changed.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much @s_ha_dum... appreciate you taking the time to break it down for me.